# CSS Overwrite DIV.class border-top

Tags: html, css

Friends,
I am using a major BI vendors analytics software and so far I managed
to overwrite a couple of .CSS classes with my own design choices however
it does not seem to work for the following case:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EHlB.jpg)

I tried the following two ways but those did not work:

```
DIV.clsAppPane {background-color: #000000!important;border-top: 1px solid #000000!important;} .clsAppPane {background-color: #000000!important;border-top: 1px solid #000000!important;}
```

I would be greatefull for any ideas.

Comment: Sorry for the bad format. I cant edit it :/

Comment: according to the image you posted this works. Can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: What is the rule that is overriding it? It probably has higher specificity.

Comment: Hi. In the image I edited the code directly using Google DevTools - just to see that I am at the right line of code. I dont see a rule that is overriding it.

Comment: So normally the background-color line isn't stroked out? And still doesn't work? What does it show on the calculated tab?

Comment: @metalray can you add it to fiddle?

Comment: OK. Progress.
I used hashes #.
Now in Chrome 61 and Firefox 56 the line is gone but IE 11 still shows it.


#DIV.clsAppPane {
    background-color: #000000 !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000 !important;
}

#clsAppPane {
    background-color: #000000 !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000 !important;
}

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not an answer but the only way I can add another image.

I have added the large white line. That was my doing and it works.
Now I want to get the green line (colored using Google Dev Tools just to highlight it - it is white be default) also in black or just remove it.
But...my css code does not work.

[See image for more details- larger scrren print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdFUS.jpg)

```html
/*does not work*/
DIV.clsAppPane {
    background-color: #000000!important;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000!important;
}

.clsAppPane {
    background-color: #000000!important;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000!important;
}

/*works*/
.appbar {
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 background-color:#2C2C2C;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an space before !important:

```
DIV.clsAppPane {background-color: #000000 !important;border-top: 1px solid #000000 !important;} .clsAppPane {background-color: #000000 !important;border-top: 1px solid #000000 !important;}
```